# Is there a regular surjective map $\psi\!: \mathbb{P}^2 \to X$ over $k$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-surfaces, birational-geometry

Assume there is $\varphi\!: \mathbb{P}^2 \to X$, a purely inseparable rational dominant map over a finite field $k$, where $X$ is an absolutely irreducible smooth surface over $k$. Is there a regular surjective map $\psi\!: \mathbb{P}^2 \to X$ over $k$?

Comment: Let $X$ be the blowup of $\mathbf P^2$ in a point, $i: \mathbf P^2 \dashrightarrow X$ the obvious birational map, and $\alpha: \mathbf P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^2$ a purely inseparable endomorphism. Then $i \circ \alpha$ is purely inseparable, but there is no regular map $\mathbf P^2 \rightarrow X$.

Comment: @potentiallydense : you can even take $\alpha=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbf{P}^2}$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: I don't think I follow. The OP wants to start with a purely insep. $\varphi$. In my comment $\varphi=i \circ \alpha$. Maybe I am being slow.

Comment: Thank you. What if $X$ is $K3$ surface?

Comment: @potentiallydense : The identity *is* purely inseparable, and so is $i$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: so it is. That feels strange, but I guess that is because I never thought carefully about it before. Thank you for educating me.

Comment: (I deleted a response to OP's follow question that said more or less: no, let $X$ be the Fermat $K3$ in characteristic 3.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let X be an unirational K3-surface over algebraically closed field. Its Picard lattice has rank 22. Note that map $\psi_*\psi^*: NS X \rightarrow NS X$ is equal to $\deg \psi$ . But $rk NS  \mathbb{P}^2= 1$. Thus we obtain a contradiction.